# UIAlertAction handler is non escaping?

Tags: ios, swift, lambda, uialertaction

I just want to confirm that UIAlertAction's handler is a non-escaping lambda function?

I did ctrl + right-click and looked up the UIAlertAction definition and it does not look escaping by default. Which means I should do

```
weak var wself = self
```

and use **wself** instead of **self** inside all UIAlertAction completion blocks?

Under UIKit>UIAlertController I see

```
open class UIAlertAction : NSObject, NSCopying {


public convenience init(title: String?, style: UIAlertAction.Style, handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil)
```

where the handler does not show @escaping

Comment: It _is_ an escaping closure. I don't know why you can't see it from the definition though. Maybe it's because it's from Objective-C.

Comment: Optional closures are all implicitly escaping. See [here](https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/why-optional-swift-closures-are-escaping/)

Comment: thanks @sweeper. if you want to post this as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIAlertAction handler is **escaping**

because Optional closures are all implicitly escaping (thanks to @sweeper)